# Abstraction frameworks to work with NoSQL databases

Tags: java, nosql

There are popular frameworks out there such as MyBatis (former iBatis), and Hibernate to work with relational databases.

Can I get some advice from the community on whether are there such frameworks available for NoSQL databases? i.e. MongoDB and CouchDB?

I saw some mentions of [JavATE](http://www.javate.amattioli.it/mainsite/articles/mongodb.html) from Theserverside.com, is this something similar?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please consider marking this as wiki. (In the  current form, there are  close votes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB:

- [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp)
- [Spring Data Couch](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-couchdb)
- and [others](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java)

MongoDB:

- [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/)
- [Spring Data Mongo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish through abstraction? Typically, abstraction would hide the particular implementation... so in terms of NoSQL, this would mean hiding that you are using Mongo vs Couch (for instance). But NoSQL is a generic term that refers to 4 distinct classes of implementation of data storage. One is Graph (Neo4j), Document (Mongo, Couch), Name Value, or Wide Column (like Cassandra).

While an abstraction like hibernate would make sense within one of these classes, abstracting them to what the industry calls "NoSQL" would not make a lot of sense.

Now... abstraction DOES make sense in your application code. In the java world, Spring can help you. Implement your data access layer with a Spring module (such as spring-mongo, spring-neo4j) against a java interface that just input-outputs POJOs. That's the SOLID way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have just pushed a new Spring-Data project named [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) which aims to do exactly this. It uses JPA annotations to map to any Tinkerpop blueprints nosql database (OrientDB, TitanDB are implemented as of now). This means that switching between any blueprints nosql database should be a matter of configuration.

**Note:** The project is in early stages of development.

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) allows to use the Hibernate API to drive NoSQL technoloqies.